# C# Как конвертировать System.Net.Sockets.Socket обьект в byte[]?

Tags: c#

Как конвертировать System.Net.Sockets.Socket обьект в byte array?

Comment: почему вы решили, что `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` в принципе можно конвертировать в `byte array`?

Comment: может ты хочешь считать данные с порта?

Comment: потому что вроде все обьекты = набор байтов. Мне интересно можно ли например обновить сервер держа все сокеты где-то на диске и потом вернуть их)

Comment: @MikeWaters нельзя, в объекте сокет содержит handle внутри себя. Операционная система управляем ими, и их номера привязаны к процессу. Завершится процесс - ОС подчистит все.

Comment: Смотрите, сколько неопределенности в Вашем вопросе, и сколько усилий нужно приложить, чтобы догадаться, чего Вы хотите на самом деле, причем не факт, что догадка правильная. ИМХО, есть смысл добавить информации в вопрос, хотя бы из наводящих вопросов в комментариях к нему.

Answer (score 1):

То, о чем вы пишите называется сериализацией.

Однако, для сериализации класс должен быть помечен атрибутом `Serializable`, который как раз отсутствует у класса `Socket` и это не спроста, так как Сокет- это объект операционной системы, а класс является лишь удобной оболочкой => он должен иметь хендл ОС. В этом не трудно убедится взглянув [внутрь](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/system/net/Sockets/Socket.cs,c84007a498b38b5f,references) .

Например, `Form` тоже нельзя сохранять, так как их успешно восстановить нельзя из-за хендлов, которые будут недействительны на других машинах.

Решением вашей проблемы может быть какой-нибудь промежуточный объект, куда вы сбросите все настройки и сохраните их на диск через сериализацию, а затем, когда потребуется создать объект `Socket`, то передадите в какой-нибудь фабричный метод путь к файлу, а он внутри себя сделает десериализацию и вам вернет `Socket`.